# Behaviour of fluids in thin spaces

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Suppose you have a simple setting: a thin (scale of hundreds of nanometer to single digit micrometer) but in relation to that very wide (up to millimeters) box with an input and an output hole in it.

Given how thin the space is, would a fluid even go in there and  fill out the box? How long would it take?

I had a bit of a hard time  to find literature on this, so hints in that direction would also be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read something about capillarity?

Comment: Google lubrication theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is known as a Hele Shaw cell, in which the bulk of the flow is a balance between pressure and viscosity, and around the edge of a region if fluid the balance is between pressure and surface tension.

Also look at the [Wikipedia page about Hele-Shaw flow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hele-Shaw_flow)